# Facebook Webhook test send not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-settings, facebook-webhooks

I am creating a Facebook Webhook. The callback link has been verified and so the connection should be okay.

When I further test the Webhook by pressing the test button under `feed`,
[image]
[image]

it seems it works.

However, nothing's received in my server, not even an access log in Apache. (I have checked both `ssl_access_log` and `access_log`) Any suggestion on what I have possibly missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the problem of using vhosts. The vhosts is set up by my colleague and he decided to save the access log and error log putting in other position than the default location.

Comment: how did you got it fixed ? im facing the same issue right now. Exactly the same!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to write **POST** request method ?

Facebook Webhook confirm callback URL in **GET** request, but they send event in **POST** request. So you need both **GET** and **POST** method in your server.

Comment: In that case, I would expect server would receive a 404 not found error in error log and an attempt in access log.

Comment: Yes. I've fogot this.